# How to calculate exponents in GWT 2.3?

Tags: java, math, gwt, exponent

I needed to calculate exponents using GWT 2.3 in Java. ie: x^y. There's no native power operator in Java, normally you have to import java.lang.Math to use the pow() method. But you cannot do that in GWT client side (I think?).

I did temporarily solve the problem by creating my own pow() method. But I'd guess what I wrote is probably inefficient and not as good as a native solution.

```
private long pow(int b, int e) {
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        result *= b;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So I googled for a better solution than mine and found a few people using third party libraries such as com.googlecode.gwt.math.Math. But I also found others saying these libraries only worked for GWT 2.0 or earlier because from 2.1 it was integrated within GWT. But I couldn't find any help on how to use these integrated math libraries in 2.3.

What exactly do I need to import? And how exactly do I use these libraries? Where exactly can I find official GWT documentation on these? Are they really integrated? Or should I just keep using my own method above?

Comment: It is a bit in efficient, but unless you repeatedly call `pow`, this is not going to be significant.  Bear in mind that `e` doesn't have to be large for the method to overflow and the result to be wrong.

Comment: You mean if b^e is larger than a long (10^63)?

Comment: No ... 2^63.  Now think how many iterations before that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT can translate java.lang.Math.pow(). See [this page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) for what parts of the Java runtime library can be emulated in Javascript by GWT.